# Что необходимо изучить для реализации считывания информации с сервера?

Tags: python, django, flutter

небольшое отступление:

> *Разрабатываю магазин-приложение для магазина в котором я работаю, появился шанс освободится от оков рутинной жизни, по этому прошу,
> знающие люди, уделите мне время.*

Долгое время программировал на Swift, выпустил несколько приложений, и вот появилась возможность сделать что-то стоящее, директору необходим магазин-приложение. Встал вопрос на чём писать, и что использовать, что бы сделать одну работу выпустить и на IOS & Android, выбор пал на **Flutter**, изучил, сверстал, всё супер. Для считывания информации о продуктах, изучил необходимое в **Python**, сделал обработчик xml в json, запарсил всю информацию. Теперь встал вопрос реализации сервера, решил создавать его на **Python Django**.

**Вопрос такой:**
Дорогие форумчане, пожалуйста, поделитесь ресурсами, откуда достать информацию, как правильно привязать выходящий json в базу данных? Как правильно вносить туда изменения? Простыми словами, что мне необходимо изучить, что бы реализовать задуманное?
Я себе представляю это так

1. Приложение запустилось
2. Подключилось к серверу
3. Сервер отправил определенный json, допустим с выбранными админом
   товарами или брендами
4. Пользователь тыкнул на продукт
5. Артикул/штрихкод/наименование отправилось на сервер
6. Сервер ответил json-ом товара

**За любую информацию буду премного благодарен!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для реализации Вашей задачи помимо [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/) прекрасно подойдет [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) или [Django Ninja](https://django-ninja.rest-framework.com/)

Уроки по использованию фрэймворка можно найти на Ютюбе, например [REST Framework](https://youtu.be/eQ0qBXdJbro) и [Django Ninja](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzBdW6jVwV4&t=434s)
Но учтите что Django позволяет реализовать как слабо нагруженные так и сильно нагруженные системы одними и тем же способом не предупреждая что выбранный Вами стиль (например) не подходит для сильно нагруженных систем. Будьте внимательны и не забывайте отправлять свой код на код ревью.

Удачи.

Comment: Я безумно Вам благодарен, приступлю к изучению немедленно. Всех благ!